What do pydantic's field_validator modes do?
I want to apply field validation to my Pydantic v2 model but don't understand what the mode kwarg does.
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional

from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator, Field

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    gross: Optional[float] = Field(
        default=None, le=999999, description="The total gross payment"
    )

    @classmethod
    @field_validator("gross", mode="before")
    def set_none_if_nan(cls, v):
        if pd.isna(v):
            return None
        return v

The options are:
FieldValidatorModes: TypeAlias = Literal['before', 'after', 'wrap', 'plain']

'before' and 'after' seem self-explanatory. However, if I pass MyModel(gross=float('nan') it complains that Input should be less than or equal to 999999, even though I thought the field validation would happen before validation?
Can't find an explanation in the Pydantic docs

It's here https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.8/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators

As @Anoma said in a comment, it's here in the pydantic docs

Pydantic provides multiple types of validator functions:



After validators run after Pydantic's internal parsing. They are generally more type safe and thus easier to implement.
Before validators run before Pydantic's internal parsing and validation (e.g. coercion of a str to an int). These are more flexible than After validators since they can modify the raw input, but they also have to deal with the raw input, which in theory could be any arbitrary object.
Plain validators are like a mode='before' validator but they terminate validation immediately, no further validators are called and Pydantic does not do any of its internal validation.
Wrap validators are the most flexible of all. You can run code before or after Pydantic and other validators do their thing or you can terminate validation immediately, both with a successful value or an error.



You can use multiple before, after, or mode='wrap' validators, but only one PlainValidator since a plain validator will not call any inner validators.

